# bencode Scala Any type

Tags: scala

I am porting over code that was written in Python over to Scala.

This python code `[0,{}]` creates a list of an integer and a dictionary.

The dictionary in this case will have keys that are strings, but the values can either be an int or a string.

I want to do something similar in Scala. I believe I would have to do something like:

```
List[Any] = (<int>, scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any](...))
```

I plan to bencode this list so the underlying type of 'Any' matters. How do I change the types so that the list can be bencoded?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I see a few people have written Scala bencode libraries, such as [pyronicide](https://github.com/pyronicide/scala-bencode) and down in the hierarchy of [storrent](https://github.com/danluu/storrent/blob/master/src/main/scala/Bencode.scala), or this [interesting looking blog post](http://covariantblabbering.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-beaty-of-parsing-combinators-and.html). So you could find some good ideas there.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, using `Any` is not the right thing to do in Scala.

Since your problem is that the map values can be either `Int` or `String`, rather than trying to use their common type (Any), make your own new type hierarchy to represent the possibilities:

```
sealed trait BData
case class BInt(i: Int) extends BData
case class BString(s: String) extends BData
```

Now your map will have a type signature of `Map[String, BData]`

Using `BData` as the "underlying type" is better than using `Any` because there is no ambiguity to it. It has exactly two subclasses; compared with Any, where your values might be a `List[(Foo, Bar)]`, for all the compiler knows.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take dylan answer little further.
Scala have strong type system and you should use it.
When you are using Any which is like Object in java, you lose the type.
You should define the types and let the compiler work for you:

```
sealed trait BData[T] {
  val value: T
}
implicit class BInt(val value: Int) extends BData[Int]
implicit class BString(val value: String) extends BData[String]
```

the 'implicit' declaration makes the compiler "Convert" the types for you, so you can use it like this:

```
val bDataMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, BData[_]]()
val l = List((1, bDataMap))
l(0)._2 += ("myKey1" -> "Str")
l(0)._2 += ("myKey2" -> 2)

l(0)._2("myKey1").value
```

and so on....